# How to load a C# dll in python?

Tags: c#, python, .net, cpython, python.net

how can I load a c# dll in python?

Do I have to put some extra code in the c# files? (like export in c++ files)

I don't want to use IronPython. I want to import a module to Python!

Comment: You might want to add a bit of clarification.  Are we talking about *CPython* or *IronPython*?

Comment: I want to import a module in Python (not IronPython then..)

Comment: You're going to struggle. A C# DLL is written in CIL and is not python, nor is it readable by python. You are going to either go full out .NET and use IronPython or suffer the pain of using COM. Isn't there some way you could use a native python module?

Comment: With the help of stack overflow I've done it. I've turned my C# dll into a COM InterOp DLL and then use it in a C++ DLL. After that I used ctypes to call the C++ DLL functions :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is to answer the second part of your Question
Try making  the DLL COM visible.

by using the

```
[ComVisible(true)]
```

Ok IronPython is a .net implemenatation of the Python language
The technology is going to use the DLR of the .net 4.0 when it arrives so IronPython will have more Dynamism (is that a word).
(In english if you're a Python guru, you'll feel more at home when you use IronPython)

So you may well choose IronPython, if you do that you can skip the COM visible part. Since both (C# , Iron Python) are under .Net

http://ironpython.net/

Comment: Now that I've saw Ironpython I understood what it was. I don't want that. I want to import a module in python :P

Comment: You mean Import (port) C# code to Python or Import a C# dll to Python

Comment: Import and use functions from a C# Dll in Python

Comment: I guess this solution is not available before .net 4.0? I tried with .net 2.0 but there is no option ComVisible

Comment: You've selected the (perfectly good) answer using Iron Python as the correct answer but also said you don't want that.  I have the same requirement as you so your correct answer is not helpful.

Answer (score 37):

The package [Python for.NET](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet) and the Python Implementation [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) now work the same way.

Example for a C# DLL `MyDll.dll`:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('MyDll')
from MyNamespace import MyClass
my_instance = MyClass()
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367976/calling-a-c-sharp-library-from-python) for more details.

Comment: intall it first by `pip3 install pythonnet`

Answer (score 6):

If you do not want to use solutions like [Python .NET](https://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/) or [IronPython](https://ironpython.net/) it is possible to implement a C++/CLI wrapper and use [Pythons ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) in order to load it. For example:

*The C++/CLI library CallCSharp:*

```
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) void foo()
    {
        // here you could use managed and unmanaged code
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, C# world...");
    }
```

The Python script:

```
from ctypes import cdll
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("./CallCSharp.dll")
lib.foo()
```

More examples for the use of ctypes can be [found here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/59464/ctypes.WinDLL).

I strongly recomment reading this blog: http://pragmateek.com/if-your-plumbing-doesnt-work-youre-just-not-using-enough-pipes/#more-1745

It also handles the issue that arises when the C++/CLI wrapper calls code that is in another assembly (you'd get something like a WindowsError: [Error -532462766] Windows Error 0xE0434352 from your Python script then).

Answer (score 5):

[*Python for .NET*](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/) works well if you don't want to use IronPython.

Answer (score -1):

If you want more explanation , go through with the youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lnsTJRY1jPU) where he has explained nicely.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34522231)