# Creating a wrapper for a C# library in Python

Tags: c#, python, wrapper

Main goal: Create a wrapper for a C# library, which can be used in Python (2.6).

UPDATE: Now, I have updates to the method I am using, which is however not working well.

The code for the simple C# class library:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Test
{
    [Guid("8F38030D-52FA-4816-B587-A925FDD33302")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    public interface _TestClass
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        string Eureka();
    }

    [Guid("BC3F6BB3-42C4-4F30-869A-92EA45BF68D2")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ProgId("Test.TestClass")]
    public class TestClass : _TestClass
    {
        public TestClass()
        {
        }

        public string Eureka()
        {
            return "Hudson, we no longer have a problem!";
        }
    }
}

enter code here
```

In addition to this, I went into Project Properties and enabled the setting: Register for COM interop.

Also, in order to make the class library available to COM, I ticked Signing -> Sign the Assembly, and gave it a strong key.

Furthermore, whenever I compile, I unregister the old version with:

```
regasm -u Test /tlb:Test
```

And I register it with:

> regasm Test.dll /tlb:Test

My problem is then, in the Python environment, I have the following main.py, which is not working:

```
import win32com.client

o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Test.TestClass")
```

The error is unforgiven.

thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load a C# dll in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077870/how-to-load-a-c-dll-in-python)

Comment: I've read that, and it is the same topic, however I am not figuring out my problem though.

Answer (score 3):

A alternative would be if you you use [*Python for .NET*](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/). There seem to be alpha releases for [Windows CPython 2.6 and 2.7](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pythonnet/files/) available. You could run simply:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("Your.Assembly.Name")
import Test
test = Test.TestClass()
print test.Eureka()
```

Comment: I see your answer, and I get that it is a valid solution, however I would like to make my library COM visible, because that will enable me to use it within PHP and other programming languages that has COM support.