# How to communicate from python script to C# exposed interface?

Tags: c#, wpf, ironpython

I am planning to use IronPython along with C# for following use case.

I want to expose some functions which can invoked via python script.

Such script will be invoked by C# application.

For example there could be function prepared in C# ClearUserInput() that clears some data on WPF. Then I could expose more functions via some interface.

```
public interface IScriptContract
{
   void ClearMainWindow();
   void LoadProject(string projectName);
}
```

python script:

```
print "clearing window"
ClearMainWindow() --how to cooperating with C# code?
print "load proj"
ClearMainWindow("project.proj") --how to cooperating with C# code?
```

I want user can write some script that can invoke my .net function.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: See here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367976/calling-a-c-sharp-library-from-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to create a 'host object' that is passed into the scripts that provides access to the host application (if you're familiar with web progamming, that's what the `window` instance is).

In IronPython you can use `SetVariable` on the `ScriptScope` object that is executing your code:

```
var contract = new ScriptContract();

var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
var mainScope = engine.CreateScope();

var scriptSource = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile("test.py", Encoding.Default, SourceCodeKind.File)

mainScope.SetVariable("host", contract);

scriptSource.Execute(scope);
```

From python it's then always available:

```
host.ClearMainWindow()
```