# How to call a C# code from python

Tags: c#, python, web-services, sharepoint

I wrote a C# code for connecting to Microsoft SharePoint, but i need to call it from python it means I wanna ask python to run this code, is it possible?
if yes, how can I do this?

Comment: This is not a duplicate as this is NOT the same question as calling an external script from Python.  See answers for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer would  be

```
os.system("myapp.exe")
```

Comment: dont forget `import os`

Comment: if you provide an answer for this obvious dupe, at least do it properly. `os.system` is deprecated, `subprocess` module is the preferred way. And return code should be checked.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually pretty easy. Just use NuGet to add the "UnmanagedExports" package to your .Net project. See https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports for details.

You can then export directly, without having to do a COM layer. Here is the sample C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;

class Test
{
    [DllExport("add", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static int TestExport(int left, int right)
    {
        return left + right;
    }
}
```

You can then load the dll and call the exposed methods in Python (works for 2.7)

```
import ctypes
a = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(source)
a.add(3, 5)
```

Comment: Why the answer is copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367976/calling-a-c-sharp-library-from-python)? Instead you could have provided the url...