# Calling C# code from python using pythonnet

Tags: c#, python, interop, python.net

Following is the C# code. How do I call the GenericMethod() inside the NonGenericClass from Python using pythonnet?

```
namespace CSharpTestCode
{
    public interface Person
    {
    }

    public class Employee : Person
    {
    }

    public class TempGenericClass<T>
    {
    }

    public class NonGenericClass
    {
        public static T GenericMethod<T>(TempGenericClass<T> tempGeneric) where T : class, Person
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Python code that I tried:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference(r'\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SamplePythonApp\CSharpTestCode\bin\Debug\CSharpTestCode.dll')
from CSharpTestCode import *

genericMethod = NonGenericClass.GenericMethod(TempGenericClass[Employee]())
```

Error that I got:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: GenericArguments[0], 'CSharpTestCode.TempGenericClass`1[CSharpTestCode.Employee]', on 'T GenericMethod[T](CSharpTestCode.TempGenericClass`1[T])' violates the constraint of type 'T'. ---> System.Security.VerificationException: Method CSharpTestCode.NonGenericClass.GenericMethod: type argument 'CSharpTestCode.TempGenericClass`1[CSharpTestCode.Employee]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'T'.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.GetStubIfNeeded(RuntimeMethodHandleInternal method, RuntimeType declaringType, RuntimeType[] methodInstantiation)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(Type[] methodInstantiation)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeType.ValidateGenericArguments(MemberInfo definition, RuntimeType[] genericArguments, Exception e)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(Type[] methodInstantiation)
   at Python.Runtime.MethodBinder.MatchParameters(MethodInfo[] mi, Type[] tp)
   at Python.Runtime.MethodBinder.Bind(IntPtr inst, IntPtr args, IntPtr kw, MethodBase info, MethodInfo[] methodinfo)
   at Python.Runtime.MethodBinder.Invoke(IntPtr inst, IntPtr args, IntPtr kw, MethodBase info, MethodInfo[] methodinfo)
   at Python.Runtime.MethodObject.Invoke(IntPtr target, IntPtr args, IntPtr kw, MethodBase info)
   at Python.Runtime.MethodBinding.tp_call(IntPtr ob, IntPtr args, IntPtr kw)
```

Comment: Do you mean an embedded IronPython interpreter? Otherwise you can't call it directly, you have to expose it somehow (many different ways for that)

Comment: I'm using pythonnet. I'm trying to build this code as class library and python will access this code through .dll

Comment: I don't know the python syntax to call this method since it has generic type parameter in both method name and in method argument

Comment: This related question may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367976/calling-a-c-sharp-library-from-python

Comment: @bavaza I already gone through this question. But that's not what I required

Comment: Did you look at Generics section of pythonnet tutorial? http://www.python4.net

Comment: @denfromufa I read that page too. but they didn't specified my requirement

Comment: but did you even try calling this generic method? if yes, can you show the error that you are getting?

Comment: @denfromufa I added the python code that I tried along with the exception that I received. can you please refer the edited question?

Comment: Reading the error message, I'm guessing pythonnet was not able to resolve that `Employee` is a `Person`. Care to remove the constraint from `NonGenericClass.GenericMethod` and try again? Alternatively, call `TempGenericClass[Person]()`

Comment: But I need to find some way to resolve this. I'm using a .dll for my project. In that, few methods are defined like this. I need to call those methods from my python project.

Comment: @Developer - I suggested the above as part of the debug process.

Comment: @bavaza you were on the right track, see my answer

Comment: @Developer - glad to help :-)

Comment: Thanks @bavaza :)

Comment: your code works @denfromufa. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should admit that pythonnet is not supposed to crash CPython interpreter even on this bad example of generic call with invalid arguments to the method.

Here is how to properly make your generic calls with pythonnet, notice how passing wrong types fails properly:

```
In [3]: NonGenericClass.GenericMethod[Person](TempGenericClass[Person]())


In [4]: NonGenericClass.GenericMethod[Employee](TempGenericClass[Employee]())


In [5]: NonGenericClass.GenericMethod[Person](TempGenericClass[Employee]())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-d13751f7586f> in <module>()
----> 1 NonGenericClass.GenericMethod[Person](TempGenericClass[Employee]())

TypeError: No method matches given arguments


In [6]: NonGenericClass.GenericMethod[Employee](TempGenericClass[Person]())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-04c3c0db6c6b> in <module>()
----> 1 NonGenericClass.GenericMethod[Employee](TempGenericClass[Person]())

TypeError: No method matches given arguments
```