# Using .net API with python packages

Tags: c#, python, .net, numpy, hardware

I am interested to control a number of instruments which has an API written in C# .NET. Based on my experience, if I use IronPython then I can't use python packages like Numpy and Scipy. However, I wanted to see if there is another way to call the .net libraries and be able to use python to implement my control and data analysis algorithms?

Comment: short answer is you can't. unless the .net library implements COM interface

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367976/calling-a-c-sharp-library-from-python

Comment: And https://pythonnet.github.io/