# Extending IronPython with C#

Tags: c#, ironpython

I'm currently planning to use C# in ironpython for a simple winform GUI, but I didn't find any documentation on the [offical website](https://ironpython-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/net-api/extending.html), so I'm just wondering if anyone have idea to integrate C# in ironpython ?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367976/calling-a-c-sharp-library-from-python  -This is the first question that shows up on the **Frequent** section of the *ironpython* tag. May be helpful with implementation

Comment: @Symon Sorry, I mean call c# code in ironpython, not calling python code in c#

Comment: What are you struggling with? You can just load .NET assemblies in IronPython and call them

Comment: @whtitefall , I've updated the link! My apologize, I misread

Comment: @UnholySheep So, I want to transfering data from ironpython to c# winform and plot a cartesian chart, is there a way to do this

Comment: If that is your overall issue, I believe it may be easier to just read the data from the form and go from there.