# There is a python bytes( from img) , how can I handle it in C# ,and convert to a byte[ ] or a image stream?

Tags: python, c#, .net, python-3.x

Now I got a python bytes like this: `b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x80\x00\x03'`, and it's from an image, how can I handle it in C# , and convert to a `byte[ ]` and then return it  as a `Bitmap`?

Here is my Python code:

```
fig = plt.figure() 
canvas = fig.canvas buffer = io.BytesIO() 
canvas.print_png(buffer) 
bin_data = buffer.getValue() 
buffer.close() 

#Excuting reults like this:
bin_data : b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x80\x00\x03'  # just a sample 
list(bin_data) :[0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 128, 0, 3] # sample
```

Is there any way to handle it in C#(client) and transform `bin_data/list(bin_data)` to a C# `byte[]` or an image Stream ?

Comment: How are you receiving these bytes from python to c#?

Comment: string, str(bin_data) , or a arr like this: ["0","0","0","0","7","128",.....]

Comment: What specifically is the issue? Please provide a [mcve], and see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this. The easiest is probably to save the bytes to a file, then load that file in C# with something like [`ReadAllBytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes?view=netcore-3.1).

In Python you can save the bytes by opening a file in binary mode, then writing the bytes:

```py
f = open("my_file_name.bin", "wb")
f.write(bin_data)
```

Then you could use Python's `subprocess` to invoke your C# application, or follow along [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367976/calling-a-c-sharp-library-from-python) if you want to integrate your C# code directly into your Python application.

Comment: the problem is that python server side and C# client side was totally separate, and python server side also have no permissions  save images,

Comment: You will have to send the bytes over the network then, you could [base64 encode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) the binary data and send it as text