# How do I connect a python module to a C # project?

Tags: python, c#, c++, dll, nuitka

I have several options, but I do not know which one is more optimal and easier to develop.

- Creating a `.dll` file to connect to the project
- Convert the project code to C #
- Rewrite the source code in C # (looks unrealistic considering the use of third-party libraries)

Nuitka seems to be suitable for these purposes. At the moment, my implementation of porting the program looks like an `.exe`, which in the output gives `.jpg` and `.json` file, however that doesn't quite suit me.

How can this be done? I would be grateful for an example with code.

**EDIT (IMPORTANT)** Need solution without using Python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

[Calling a C# library from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367976/calling-a-c-sharp-library-from-python) I think it will be help :) Also check https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html
If you have more questions write comment

Comment: I read the question as so OP is trying to call python from C#, not the other way round.

Comment: Oh ok, my bad, so he can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367976/calling-a-c-sharp-library-from-python) :)

Comment: @Mondonno It looks like exactly the same what you dropped earlier, and that's not quite right.