# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. Python 3.6 import dotnet

Tags: python, c#, .net, python-3.x, python-import

I am running python 3.6, I have already installed the correct version of dotnet from the [official site](https://pypi.org/project/dotnet/). When I launched python console and import dotnet, I got the following error:

```
File "...\lib\site-packages\dotnet\moduleloader.py", line 24, in <module>
    from dotnet import PyDotnet as _dotnet
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Spotted one of the comment from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367976/calling-a-c-sharp-library-from-python/29854281), if you rename boost_python3-vc141-mt-1_64.dll to boost_python3-vc150-mt-1_64.dll it will solve the issue, reason is unknown. The dll should site under Lib/site-packages/dotnet.