# How to import submodule from a C# dll in Python

Tags: c#, python, .net, namespaces, python.net

I added a dll using `pythonnet` to my Python script like this:

```
import os
import clr
clr.AddReference(os.path.join(os.path.abspath('.'), 'dlls', 'Supplier.Bundle.dll'))
import Supplier.Bundle
```

It works just fine, I can call methods or instantiate classes right from the `Supplier.Bundle` namespace, but when I want to call a method from a nested namespace like `Supplier.Bundle.Features` I got the error:

```
AttributeError: Features
```

I also tried the following:

```
import Supplier.Bundle.Features
```

Which throws:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Supplier.Bundle.Features'; 'Supplier.Bundle' is not a package
```

Using the same dll in C# works just fine:

```
using Supplier.Bundle.Features
```

So my question is: how to access classes and methods of nested namespaces of a C# dll within Python3.x using `pythonnet`?

Comment: Please don't tag-spam, if you want to ask about python, there should not be tag `c#` or `.net`

Comment: I guess it's closely related to .net and C#. Just like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077870/how-to-load-a-c-sharp-dll-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load a C# dll in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077870/how-to-load-a-c-sharp-dll-in-python)

Comment: I can load the dll, what I want is to get access to classes of nested namespaces within the imported module.

Comment: Have you seen this answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20263498/4697963) ?

Comment: @MarkBenovsky Yes, I did but that still not answers my question. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve the problem.
Actually the `Supplier.Bundle.dll` had two other dependencies, so after copying the missing dlls to the project root, the import became error free.

Additionally the `pythonnet` package should've thrown more specific exceptions about the problem. That would've made the troubleshooting even more easier.

More on the issue: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/516

Answer (score 1):

I think I know a workaround for it. Use `from module import`. 
See the following example:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Windows.Forms')
#import System.Windows.Forms                # <-- not working
from System.Windows.Forms import MessageBox # <-- working

MessageBox.Show('Hello World')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately I got an `ImportError: cannot import name '...'` as the result of this approach.

Comment: Does it just happen with your `Supplier.Bundle.dll`? And can you use a nested namespace like `import System.Windows.Forms`?

Comment: Yes, seems like.