# Calling C# dll from Python

Tags: c#, python, dll

I have been trying to call a C# dll from python with no success. 
My C# class is:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public double Add_It(double x1, double x2, double x3, double x4)
        {
            return x1 * x4 * (x1 + x2 + x3) + x3;
        }
     }
}
```

and Python code is:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('C:/Users/MNCHR/Desktop/ClassLibrary1.dll')
from ClassLibrary1 import Class1
```

The error is

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Class1'

please advise

Comment: Whats the full Namespace of Class1?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2077878/2147110

Comment: As it can be seen in the C# code the namespace is ClassLibrary1

Comment: I know my question might be a duplication but foe some reasons procedure suggested in similar posts does not work for me