# Python 3: import dll with ctypes or numpy.ctypeslib

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll, ctypes

I want to work with the APIs of the program of structural analysis (civil engineering) [Autodesk Robot Structural Analysis](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/robot-structural-analysis-products/getting-started?sort=score).
With `IronPython` I initialize the variables as follows:

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(‘mypfad\Interop.RobotOM.dll’)
from RobotOM import *
robapp = RobotApplicationClass()
robproj = robapp.Project
robstruct = robproj.Structure
```

With `robstruct` I can call the API functions and continue working.

Now I’d like to do the same with `Python 3`. I have tried with `ctypes` and with `numpy.ctypeslib` without success:

```
import ctypes
lib_ctypes = ctypes.cdll[‘mypfad\Interop.RobotOM.dll']
print(lib_ctypes)
<CDLL 'mypfad \Interop.RobotOM.dll', handle 1a1ff900000 at 0x1a1e8e22710>

import numpy
lib_numpy = numpy.ctypeslib.load_library('Interop.RobotOM.dll', 'mypfad’)
print(lib_ numpy)
<CDLL 'mypfad\Interop.RobotOM.dll', handle 1a1ffb40000 at 0x1a1ffb194e0>
```

And I don’t how to continue.

My questions are: is this the right way and how shall I continue?

**Edited 05.10.2018**

Original code with `IronPython`:

```
import clr

# Add Robot Structural Analysis API reference
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(
    'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\Extensions 2018\Framework\Interop\Interop.RobotOM.dll'
)

# Add needed import to be able to use Robot Structural Analysis objects
from RobotOM import *

# Connect to the running instance of Robot Structural Analysis
robapp = RobotApplicationClass()

# Get a reference of the current project
robproj = robapp.Project

# Get a reference of the current model
robstruct = robproj.Structure
```

An attempt according to the comment of `The Machine`:

```
import ctypes

my_dll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(
    'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\Extensions 2018\Framework\Interop\Interop.RobotOM.dll'
)

robapp = my_dll.RobotApplicationClass()
robproj = robapp.Project
robstruct = robproj.Structure
```

Result:

```
AttributeError: function 'RobotApplicationClass' not found
```

**Edited 16.10.2018**

Third attempt:

```
from ctypes import cdll
my_dll = cdll.LoadLibrary(
    'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\Extensions 2019\Framework\Interop\Interop.RobotOM.dll'
)
my_dll.RobotApplicationClass()
```

Result:

```
AttributeError: function 'RobotApplicationClass' not found
```

Comment: Hmm, I am not an expert in this area, but that seems a *.net* *.dll*. *ctypes* only knows to import from the *.dll* stuff that's *C* style.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from ctypes import*
your_dll = cdll.LoadLibrary(‘mypfad\Interop.RobotOM.dll ')
```

If it is succesfully loaded than you can aces to all of  classes and function in that dll file . You can call theme with `your_dll.nameofclass` .

Comment: I've been working in your idea, @The Machine, with no result. Please, see the edited text.

Comment: It semés someone succesfully had done it    . Here the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077870/how-to-load-a-c-sharp-dll-in-python .

Comment: I’ve tried with the proposal of anhoppe said here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077870/how-to-load-a-c-sharp-dll-in-python) as indicated by @The Machine. Something seems not to work.

Comment: Please can you post it the problem