# How to load a C# dll in python? - Error

Tags: c#, python

I am trying to call a C# dll in python. 
I used these 2 approaches: 
[link1](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-framework/dynamic-language-integration-in-a-c-world/)
[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077870/how-to-load-a-c-sharp-dll-in-python/51875827#51875827)

But i am not able to use this line:

```
import clr 

clr.AddReference('MyDll') 

from MyNamespace import MyClass

my_instance = MyClass()
```

But I get an error: in this line:

```
from MyNamespace import MyClass
```

cannot import name `MyClass`

Does anybody now why?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367976/calling-a-c-sharp-library-from-python. Can you give us detail on the package used and installed?

Comment: I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2017 and JetBrains PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2 x64. Was that your question?