# IronPython v Python 3.11 - Importing .dll Libraries in Python 3.11

Tags: python-3.x, ironpython, dllimport, autodesk

I am having an issue importing a .dll library in Python 3.11.

For IronPython, the import is successfull and looks as follows (example is for using the API of a structural analysis package called Robot from Autodesk):

```python
import clr
clr.AddReferenceAndFilePath('C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Robot Structural Analysis Professional 2023\Exe\Interop.RobotOM.dll')
import RobotOM as rbt
print(dir(rbt))
```

And the output is a comprehensive list of all members functions, methods and attributes of the library:

```python
['DontUseIt', 'DontUseItClass', 'IDontUseIt', 'IRBestBendType', 'IRBestCalcErrors', 'IRBestCalcParamsData',  ...]
```

Following a similar syntactical approach in Python 3.11, I was expecting the same results as that of IronPython:

```python
import ctypes
RobotOM = ctypes.WinDLL(r'C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Robot Structural Analysis Professional 2023\Exe\Interop.RobotOM.dll')
print(dir(RobotOM))
```

The output is as follows:

```python
['_FuncPtr', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_func_flags_', '_func_restype_', '_handle', '_name']
```

Various other approaches yield the same results, such as:

```python
import ctypes
RobotOM = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(r'C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Robot Structural Analysis Professional 2023\Exe\Interop.RobotOM.dll')
```

My question: how can I replicate the successfull import of the .dll library in Python 3.11? With IronPython it is possible, surely the same should be possible for Python 3.11?

Comment: Everything works as expected. On one hand you have *.NET* and on the other *C*. To mimic *IronPython* behavior, you should install some *.NET* *.dll* handler package (if available - https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet ?).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load a C# dll in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077870/how-to-load-a-c-sharp-dll-in-python)